# Anonymized Spatial Conflict Assessment - Suggested Approaches?

Tags: encryption, elgamal-encryption

**Scenario:**

1. There are 3 people: PERSON1, PERSON2, and PERSON3
2. PERSON1 and PERSON2 each have a 2-dimensional polygon on an x,y
   plane
3. It is PERSON3's job to assess whether the polygons overlap
4. However, PERSON1 and PERSON2 must encode their polygons in such a
   way that PERSON3 cannot identify the location of their polygons, nor
   is it possible for PERSON3 to decrypt the polygons.
5. Despite this, PERSON3 must assess whether the two polygons overlap
6. PERSON1 and PERSON2 must also not be able to identify the location
   of the other's polygon
7. What encryption scheme could achieve this?

For context, the problem I am trying to solve is: **decentralized, fully anonymized claims management**.

Banks, insurance companies, and land program administrators all need to know whether their spatial (and temporal) claim is exclusive. Banks need to control for unwanted cross-collateralization, insurance companies need to avoid double insuring, and land program administrators (e.g. carbon programs) need to make sure there is no double-claiming. However, location is sensitive information, and revealing it on a public ledger might constitute a violation of the claimant or landowner's right to privacy. Neither the computational nodes nor other users should be able to identify a claim with a location.

I understand that there are a few homomorphic encryption schemes that might be able to achieve this, but they tend to be far too computationally expensive to run on decentralized nodes. I am wondering if there is a lightweight scheme that is specifically geared toward polygon overlap assessment.